# How can I reset session when user navigates away from page?

Tags: php, session

I've created [a session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.session.php) to keep track of some user actions on a specific page.

When user navigates away from that specific page (but still on the same site), I need to reset the session.

I can set set timer for when session expires, but that's not what I want.

How can I reset session on page navigation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make resetting the session the very first thing you do when loading a new page.

Comment: mm - unless page is reloded. But I can probably check on that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a single page that all traffic is routed through? If so you could do a simple check

```
if ($current_page != $session_page) {
    $_SESSION = array();
}
```

If you don't have a single page all traffic goes through, then you will need to reset the session at the beginning of every other page.

```
$_SESSION = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use

```
unset($_SESSION);
```

or

```
session_destroy();
```

Though note these handle slightly differently to the suggestions above. Note the second (session_destroy) will require you restart the session should you need it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can never be sure that the session is really destroyed.

But there is an old trick used in for example chat applications where a "... is leaving" message is to be printed: On unload just open a popup windows with `window.open()` that calls your logout page and then closes itself.

Comment: Oh, now I see that you have influence on the page that is navigated *to*, then you don't need the trick.

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is make a quick ajax call on unload to an unset page, much like the other answers on this page.

```
<script>
 function myAjaxCall(){
  //if using jquery
  $.ajax('unset.php');
 }
</script>

<body onunload="myAjaxCall()">
```